# Power series of $(1-x^{2})^{1/2}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

Yesterday I have found and old homework with an exercise that I couldn't do but ironically it's so difficult too right now. Is the next:

> Let $f(x)=(1-x^{2})^{1/2}$. Find a power series of the form $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_n x^{n}$ such that converges uniformly to $f(x)$ in the interval $[0,1]$.

My first thought was Taylor series of this function but I don't think that that will be a good idea. Then, searching in StackExchange I have found this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2563741/356536). I thik that is the right way, but, prove the uniformly convergence for my particular series is so difficult. Moreover, after read the Wikipedia article that the user provides, the proof of the convergence of the series are so tecnic and it's so away from my knowledge. Is there another form to prove that the series converges? Or, moreover, is there another form to obtain a power series such that converges uniformly to $f(x)$ in the interval $[0,1]$?. Even, if I can prove that the series converges, how can I prove that the series converges to $f(x)$? Maybe prove the convergence it's not difficult using the $M$-test of Weierstrass (A first idea suggested by Wikipedia article). I really aprecciate any help you can provide me. Thanks!

Comment: The radius of convergence cannot be more than $1$ because in the interior of the interval of convergence, the derivative of the power series also converges and is differentiable, and the derivative of this function approaches $\pm\infty$ at $x=\pm1.$ There is a theorem that says that in every subset of the interval of convergence that is bounded away from the endpoints of the interval, the series converges uniformly. But in some cases it doesn't converge uniformly on the interval as a whole.

Comment: I don't understand the "such that" part. There can only be one power series that converges to $f(x)$. Its mode of convergence is just a mathematical fact that has no choice to it.

Comment: I tried to say that if there is another aproximation or another from to obtain the power series. Maybe another easier form or something like that.

Comment: @Carlos Jiménez. If it were $f(x)=(1+x^{2})^{1/2}$, then using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini%27s_theorem uniform convergence can be reached, as limit is continuous. May be this helps somehow.

Comment: @zkutch Since the sign of $\displaystyle\binom{\frac12}{k}$ is $(-1)^k,$ it's exactly the other way round: you can't use the theorem for your function, but you can for the problem, here.

Comment: @Professor Vector. Do not understand what you mean. Dini's theorem need non negative case, here it is not - how cat it be used here? Topic starter have $(1-x^{2})^{1/2}$.

Comment: @zkutch Correction: the sign of $\displaystyle\binom{\frac{1}{2}}{k}$ is $(-1)^{k-1}$ starting from $k=2$, the sign of $(-x^2)^k$ is $(-1)^k,$ so the sign of the whole expression is $(-1)^k\cdot$(-1)^{k-1}=(-1)^{2k-1}=-1$. So there's monotone (decreasing) convergence to a continuous function.

Comment: @Professor Vector. I do not see second $(-1)^{k-1}$ - look down in Alex answer, there is only one. No?

Comment: Interestingly, the only closed form that Mathematica finds for the $n^{\mathrm{th}}$ term of a supposed power series is of the form $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}, meaning there would exist power series for this function, only Laurent series - which is surprising considering the given function is of such a simple nature and is not in any way pathological.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My 2 cents:
On interval $[0,1]$ Taylor series for function $f(x)=(1-x^{2})^{1/2}$ $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{\frac{1}{2}}{k}(-x^2)^k\ \ \ \ (1)$$  can be estimated by series $$\sum{}{}\frac{|\alpha(\alpha-1)\ldots(\alpha-k+1)|}{k!}$$
convergence for last series comes from [Raabe's_test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test#L=1_and_Raabe%27s_test) for $\alpha > 0$. And then Weierstrass gives uniformly convergence for (1).

Convergence of series (1) on $[0,1]$ to function $f$ is well known fact (for example Spivak "Calculus" IV edition, 495p i.e. *21 from 23), so we can conclude, that (1) is desired series, which converges uniformly to $f(x)$ in the interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: Wow. The only step that remains is to prove that the series converges to $f(x)$.

Comment: @Carlos Jiménez. It comes from that we have  representation $$(1-x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{\frac{1}{2}}{k}(-x^2)^k$$ everywhere in interval $[0,1]$. This is Teilor series for initial $f(x)$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Binomial_series . If you would like I add this to answer.

Comment: But, even if a function is infinitely differentiable, Taylor series of the function may not be convergent to te function.

Comment: Yes, there is well know example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Approximation_error_and_convergence, but it is not our case. There is also generalization for bounded continuous function for Teilor theorem i.e. our case: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Generalization .

Comment: I'm really embarrassed but the last comment contains things that escapes from my knowledge. I only have tools of the clasic Taylor series.

Comment: Understand. Let's make it without any link: we can consider difference between function and partial sum and estimate rest directly. Would you like me to write proof?

Comment: Yes, please. If possible, I want to see your proof.

Comment: Ok.  Can you tell, please, from which source you are familiar with tools of the classic Taylor series? For example, are you familiar with Cauchy form of the remainder?

Comment: Yes. The remainder forms, the theorems about the remainder and anything about it. All the topics that appears in Spivak's Calculus.

Comment: Fine. I have IV edition and everything is on 495p (i.e. *21 from 23). All what I can do is write it more bad, then Spivac. But, may be brought is enough?

Comment: Don't worry. Everything you've been doing already helps me a lot.

Comment: Ok. So, do you agree, that Spivac *21 from 23 + my answer about uniformly convergence close question? (I'm worried about my promise).

Comment: Yes. I'm agree with it. It's the solution to my question.

Comment: Nice. Would you like I add it to my answer?

Comment: Yes, please. I want to see your solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is called a Generalized Binomial series.
$$
(1-x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{\frac{1}{2}}{k}(-x^2)^k
$$
For the binomial coefficient, write
$$
\binom{\alpha}{k} = \alpha(\alpha-1)\ldots(\alpha-k+1)\times\frac{1}{k!}
$$
Now subsitute $\alpha = \frac{1}{2}$ to get $\frac{(-1)^{k-1}(2k-3)!!}{2^k k!}$. You can simpliy further to get $c_k$.

Comment: But this doesn't address the question of uniform convergence.